# Detect if runtime is device or desktop (ARM or x86/x64)

Tags: windows-iot

How to detect if a UWP/Iot Core application is being run on an ARM processor or a desktop processor (x86/x64)? Alternatively, is there any other way to detect if the application is run on desktop Windows or on a device? It would also help to detect if the application was launched in Visual Studio or not.

I already tried the *Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation* class but it does not provide this information.

Googling has not taken me further.

Comment: I haven't done nearly as much UWP development as I should have. I *think* this looks about right: https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/ . Could you take a quick look and confirm whether it's what you're after (specifically *Package.Current.Id.Architecture.ToString()*)?

Comment: @goobering : thank you! You should have written that as an answer as it completely solved my problem!

Comment: Note that this probably isn't as reliable as you want--some full-sized computers run ARM (Chromebooks, apparently some forthcoming blade servers), and Android can run on Atom.

Comment: @chrylis : thank you for the comment! In our case, we actually implemented the functionality with the OS family information also provided by the Package class (as suggested in the answer of @goobering). This is not about anything going to production, it is just to ease things to university students programming our device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This article](https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/) on [suchan.cz](https://www.suchan.cz/) describes how to access several system details in a UWP application:

> - current OS family - phone/desktop/...
> - current OS build number - 10.0.10240.16413
> - current OS architecture - x86/x64/ARM
> - current App Display Name - Battery Tile for instance
> - current App Version - 3.0.2.0
> - current Device manufacturer - Nokia
> - current Device model - Lumia 1520

Specifically, the code used to access the system architecture is:

```
// get the package architecure
    Package package = Package.Current;
    string systemArchitecture = package.Id.Architecture.ToString();
```

Comment: Package is in namespace Windows.ApplicationModel